# How to convert object[] to List<string> in one line of C# 3.0?

Tags: c#, generics, list, casting

ok I give up, how do you do this in one line?

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    //List<string> fields = values.ToList<string>();
    //List<string> fields = values as List<string>;
    //List<string> fields = (List<string>)values;

    List<string> fields = new List<string>();
    foreach (object value in values)
    {
        fields.Add(value.ToString());
    }

    //process the fields here knowning they are strings
    ...
}
```

Comment: Technically it's C# 3.0, which can be used to target .NET frameworks 2.0, 3.0, or 3.5 in VS2008. Confusing, I know :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Are you using C# 3.0 with LINQ? It's pretty easy then:

```
List<string> fields = values.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere that the object array was actually an array of strings.  This answer is correct because ie duplicates *exactly* what the OP posted in a one-liner.

Comment: @Andrew: Yeah, good point. I clearly read the question too quickly. Caveat mentioned in my post now.

Comment: as you correctly assumed from the context, the objects are coming from XAML and theoretically could be of any type, so with this answer when I send an integer, it gets correctly converted to a string, perfect

Comment: This is technically a two-liner if you count the using directive :D

Answer (score 17):

If you have LINQ available (in .NET 3.5) and C# 3.0 (for extension methods), then there is quite a nice one liner:

```
var list = values.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

You're not going get anything much shorter that what you've posted for .NET 2.0/C# 2.0.

**Caveat:** I just realised that your `object[]` isn't necessarily of type `string`. If that is in fact the case, go with Matt Hamilton's method, which does the job well. If the element of your array are in fact of type `string`, then my method will of course work.

Comment: great answer - much simpler than a linq select.

Comment: Note that this will fail if any value is not a string.

Comment: .Cast is very terse, thanks, nice to know, but in this case my objects as you noted in your caveat, are coming from a XAML Multibinding and could theoretically be any object and hence this would break if I sent a non-string

Comment: @Edward Tanguay: Yeah, it now makes sense why you were doing that loop. No problem...

Answer (score 9):

C# 2.0:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>(Array.ConvertAll<object,string>(values, new Converter<object,string>(Convert.ToString)));
```

Answer (score 4):

One more variant that might be correct:

```
List<string> list = values.OfType<string>().ToList();
```

This will filter out any objects in the original list that are not `string` objects, instead of either throwing an exception or trying to convert them all into strings.

Comment: .OfType is very interesting, will remember it, but in this context, I need to display the three values whatever they are (string, integer, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

```
Array.ConvertAll(inputArray, p => p.ToString())
```

This converts an array of `object` type to array of `string`. You can convert to other type array by changing the lambda expression.

Answer (score 2):

While not a one liner with respect to List<> declaration, gives you same effect without requiring Linq.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
Array.ForEach(values, value => list.Add(value.ToString()));
```